# WPF - Запрет наложения элементов друг на друга

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-n-drop

Есть Grid и на нем несколько одинаковых элементов управления, которые можно перетаскивать и менять местами. Есть ли способы в WPF запретить наложения этих элементов друг на друга при перетаскивании?

Класс по перемещению:

```
public class MoveShape : Thumb
{
    public MoveShape()
    {
        base.DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(MoveShape_DragDelta);
    }

    void MoveShape_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        CustomControl designerItem = this.DataContext as CustomControl;

        if (designerItem != null)
        {
            double minTop = double.MaxValue;

            double top = designerItem.Top;
            minTop = double.IsNaN(top) ? 0 : Math.Min(top, minTop);

            double deltaVertical = Math.Max(-minTop, e.VerticalChange);
            designerItem.Top += deltaVertical;

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
/// <summary>Top</summary>
    private double _top;
    /// <summary>Top</summary>
    private ObservableCollection<CustomControlVM> _customControls = new ObservableCollection<CustomControlVM>();

    /// <summary>Move Control</summary>
    public ICommand MoveControl { get; }

    public double Top
    {
        get { return _top; }
        set
        {
            if (_top != value)
            {
                _top = value;
                NotifyChanged("Top");
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<CustomControlVM> CustomControls
    {
        get { return _customControls; }
    }

    public CustomControlVM()
    {
        MoveControl = new RelayCommand(Move);
    }

    void Move(object newPosition)
    {
        Top = (double)newPosition;
    }
```

View:

```
<Grid x:Name="GridPanel" Background="WhiteSmoke">
    <ScrollViewer Name="DesignerScrollViewer"
                      Background="Transparent"
                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CustomControls}"
                  Background="Transparent">
            <ItemsControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width"
                     Value="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=GridPanel}" />
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.Resources>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=GridPanel}"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ContentControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                            <custom:CustomControl />
                        </ContentControl>
                    </Grid>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Canvas IsHitTestVisible="False">
        <Rectangle Opacity="0.4" Name="DraggedImageContainer" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Скажу сразу, что мне нужно перемещать контролы только по вертикали, поэтому операции по перемещению по горизонтали я не писал.

Comment: мне кажется, это только ручным обсчетом координат можно сделать

Comment: да, такие способы есть, но они зависят от текущей реализации

Comment: А как именно у вас реализовано перетаскивание?

Comment: VladD, дополнил. Реализовано по паттерну MVVM.